# how can matrix multiplication be described in traffic cordinations?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In one of our lectures, spacial Interaction was represented as matrices. but when It's come to multiplications how would you merge spacial interactions with the result of multiplication.

To make things more clear. I did some web search on this. but I couldn't find anything that helps me to come to direct answer. let me describe more of this.
[image]

this is a basic spatial interaction in matrix form. so we can find this matrix easily as in the picture above.

Now if one say to multiply this matrix with another matrix obviously we have a solution. But now how would you describe each entries of the result in terms of spacial Interactions?

I'm still new to matrices, a simple clarification would be great. thanks

Comment: A solution to what? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: yes. the solution is one the we get from multiplication. I need to be described each entries in A,B,C,D(look at spatial interaction).

Comment: Not being familiar with "spatial interaction", could I ask what the numbers in the matrix mean?